# how to make a pyqt tabbed interface with scroll bars?

Tags: qt, python-2.7, tabs, pyqt, scrollbar

How can you had independent scroll bars to a tabbed interface in Qt? This is what I tried, but there are no scroll bars, and everything is very small.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Tabs Example')

    tab1 = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    tab1_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab1)

    text_browser_1 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_1)
    text_browser_2 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_2)
    text_browser_3 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_3)
    text_browser_4 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_4)
    text_browser_5 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_5)
    text_browser_6 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_6)
    text_browser_7 = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
    tab1_layout.addWidget(text_browser_7)

    tab2 = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    tab2_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab2)

    button_1 = QtGui.QPushButton()
    tab2_layout.addWidget(button_1)
    button_2 = QtGui.QPushButton()
    tab2_layout.addWidget(button_2)
    button_3 = QtGui.QPushButton()
    tab2_layout.addWidget(button_3)

    tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    tab_widget.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
    tab_widget.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2")
    main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    main_layout.addWidget(tab_widget)
    main_layout.addStretch(1)
    window.setLayout(main_layout)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using QScrollArea incorrectly. You need to set a widget that will be displayed in the area using `QScrollArea::setWidget` and  then add contents to this widget. You also need to specify `setWidgetResizable(true)`.

```
tab1 = QtGui.QScrollArea()
tab1.setWidget(QtGui.QWidget())
tab1_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab1.widget())
tab1.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks. Is there a way to make the whole QTabWidget resizeable too? right now if you change the window size it shrinks but doesn't expand.

Comment: It's because you've added a space using `main_layout.addStretch(1)`. Try to remove it.